# PTIJ: Travelling on named roads which have a Halachic status

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

There are many streets and roads with food and Biblically related names. Would such streets impart Kedushah, Tumah, or other Halachic statuses on the traveler?

For example, is it Assur to travel on [Ives Dairy Road](https://goo.gl/maps/tn3paMrLV1k) while Fleishig, or on [Hamburger Road](https://goo.gl/maps/5GBiRsnyPz52) while Milchig (from hard cheese like Parmesan)?

Similarly, can one travel on [North Bread Street](https://goo.gl/maps/PYvP46c3jPU2) or [Cracker Street](https://goo.gl/maps/J6LYaVuh5oR2) during Pesach? Do only Sefardim have a Heter to travel on [Rice Street](https://goo.gl/maps/JHtJQeebMrL2) or [Rice Road](https://goo.gl/maps/U99TAZBAYtx) during Pesach? Must they check each crevice for Chametz?

Must one wait until Moshiach comes to be able to travel on [Pork Avenue](https://goo.gl/maps/vbyBrZ96iYF2), assuming it chews its cud?

Which part of [Giraffe Road](https://goo.gl/maps/VpHSE9KqG782) may one enter and exit?

May a Rasha travel on [Leviathan Street](https://goo.gl/maps/LsXeujpP6bA2)?

May a Kohen travel on [Tamei Road](https://goo.gl/maps/pCdh5qtojN42)?

May one walk on [Leather Street](https://goo.gl/maps/kV28SCLAGMK2) during Yom Kippur?

Are only gentiles allowed to travel on [Goy Road](https://goo.gl/maps/bAWX51D6qe42)? Can the inverse be said about [Jew Road](https://goo.gl/maps/1JfN4hDYDN32)?

Is it a violation of V'nishmartem Meod L'nafshoseichem to travel on [Danger Street](https://goo.gl/maps/7MHPj7ejNh52)?

According to Halacha, can one who's Makpid Cholov Yisroel travel on [Milk Road](https://goo.gl/maps/885zftcWTX42) if it is maintained by gentiles? What if a Jew is always present?

Can one be Yotzei going to Gehinnom by going to [Hell Street](https://goo.gl/maps/xsurs8iCi6s)?

Can one attain Dveikus L'Hashem by living on [Hashem Drive](https://goo.gl/maps/X4M77RunTG52)?

Did Mordechai refuse to travel on [Haman Way](https://goo.gl/maps/UmP7vsmTDcS2)?

Do we have a Chiyuv to destroy [Amalek Street](https://goo.gl/maps/kA5FeRhrGe22)?

Is it suggested for converts to travel through [Jethro's Road](https://goo.gl/maps/jDa7i4pe43q)?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: צדיק ה' בכל דרכיו  - You can find Hashem's righteousness in every street

Comment: How on earth (sorry) did you think to look for all of these?

Comment: Google Maps helped me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must tackle each case on a case-by-case basis. This is what the Talmud ([Moed Katan 5](https://www.sefaria.org/Moed_Katan_5a.23)) teaches:

> אריב"ל כל השם אורחותיו זוכה ורואה בישועתו של הקדוש ברוך הוא שנאמר ושם דרך אל תקרי ושם אלא ושם דרך אראנו בישע אלהים
>
> With regard to the verse from Psalms cited above, Rabbi Yehoshua ben Levi said: Whoever appraises his ways in this world and contemplates how to act in the most appropriate way possible merits seeing the salvation of the Holy One, Blessed be He, as it is stated: “And to him who orders his way.” Do not read it as vesam, who orders; rather, read it as vesham, and appraises. With this reading, the verse indicates that one who appraises his ways, him will I show the salvation of God.

Answer (score 4):

Every road is another way to serve God. As Mishlei 3:6 says:

> בְּכָל־דְּרָכֶ֥יךָ דָעֵ֑הוּ וְ֝ה֗וּא יְיַשֵּׁ֥ר אֹֽרְחֹתֶֽיךָ׃
>
> In all your roads you shall know Him, and He will straighten your streets.